# Extracting p from div class python to get addresses

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**Currently the code**: Finds the urls for all gyms and puts in csv like so:

```
https://www.lifetime.life/life-time-locations/al-vestavia-hills.html
https://www.lifetime.life/life-time-locations/az-biltmore.html
```

**What I want it to do**: I am having trouble extracting the address from each url. My attempt at the address part is is in the 4th and 5th line from the bottom of "The code" below. The exact error is:

```
gymrow.append(address_line1[0].text)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**The code***:

```
import urllib2
import BeautifulSoup

initial_url = "https://www.lifetime.life"

request = urllib2.Request("https://www.lifetime.life/view-all-locations.html")
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(response)
with open('gyms2.csv', 'w') as gf:
  gymwriter = csv.writer(gf)
  for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    if '/life-time-locations/' in a['href']:
      gymurl1 = (urlparse.urljoin(initial_url, a.get('href')))
      sitemap_content = requests.get(gymurl1).content
      gymrow = [gymurl1]

      address_line1 = soup.select('p[class~=small m-b-sm p-t-1] > span[class~=btn-icon-text]')
      gymrow.append(address_line1[0].text)

      print(gymrow)
      gymwriter.writerow(gymrow)
      time.sleep(3)
```

[Image of inspect element: the p class, span class and the address I want to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d6uv.png)

Thank you very much!

Comment: first check what you get in response. Server may send different HTML for different devices (phone, tablet, desktop) and you mayh need `User-Agent` header. OR it may block your code and it may sends warning message in HTML - so save `response` HTML in file  and open in browser to see what you get.

Comment: I don't understand why you use `urllib2.Requests` and `requests.get` if can use one of them.

Comment: your read data from subpage but you don't create `soup` and you search on main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get HTML from subpage but you don't convert to `soup` so you search on main page

```
response = requests.get(gymurl)
sub_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
```

I had also problem with CSS selector

```
address_line = sub_soup.select('p.small.m-b-sm.p-t-1 span.btn-icon-text')
```

Some pages doesn't have elements in this place and it raise error so I use `try/except` to catch it.

---

Tested on Python 3 because on Python 2 `.select()` didn't work for me

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse
import csv
import time

initial_url = "https://www.lifetime.life"

response = requests.get("https://www.lifetime.life/view-all-locations.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

with open('gyms2.csv', 'w') as gf:
    gymwriter = csv.writer(gf)
    for a in soup.findAll('a'):
        if '/life-time-locations/' in a['href']:
            gymurl = urllib.parse.urljoin(initial_url, a.get('href'))
            print(gymurl)

            response = requests.get(gymurl)
            sub_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

            try:
                address_line = sub_soup.select('p.small.m-b-sm.p-t-1 span.btn-icon-text')
                gymrow = [gymurl, address_line[0].text.strip()]
                print(gymrow)
                gymwriter.writerow(gymrow)
                time.sleep(3)
            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)
```

---

**EDIT:** Python 2 using `find()` instead of `select()`

```
import requests
import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib2
import time

initial_url = "https://www.lifetime.life"

response = requests.get("https://www.lifetime.life/view-all-locations.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

with open('gyms2.csv', 'w') as gf:
    gymwriter = csv.writer(gf)
    for a in soup.findAll('a'):
        if '/life-time-locations/' in a['href']:
            gymurl = urllib2.urlparse.urljoin(initial_url, a.get('href'))
            print(gymurl)

            response = requests.get(gymurl)
            sub_soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

            try:
                address_line = sub_soup.find('p', {'class': 'small m-b-sm p-t-1'}).find('span', {'class': 'btn-icon-text'})
                gymrow = [gymurl, address_line.text]
                print(gymrow)
                gymwriter.writerow(gymrow)
                time.sleep(3)
            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)
```

---

**EDIT:** It seems there are many versions of pages. Every page may need separted `try/except`. But instead of putting second try/except inside first `except` I use `continue` to skip next `try/except` if first `try` works correctly.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse
import csv
import time

initial_url = "https://www.lifetime.life"

response = requests.get("https://www.lifetime.life/view-all-locations.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

with open('gyms2.csv', 'w') as gf:
    gymwriter = csv.writer(gf)
    for a in soup.findAll('a'):
        if '/life-time-locations/' in a['href']:
            gymurl = urllib.parse.urljoin(initial_url, a.get('href'))
            print(gymurl)

            response = requests.get(gymurl)
            sub_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

            try:
                address_line = sub_soup.select('p.small.m-b-sm.p-t-1 span.btn-icon-text')
                gymrow = [gymurl, address_line[0].text.strip()]
                print('type 1:', gymrow)
                gymwriter.writerow(gymrow)
                time.sleep(3)
                continue # go back to `for`            
            except Exception as ex:
                print('ex:', ex)

            try:
                address_line = sub_soup.find('div', {'class': 'btn-resp-md'}).find('p')
                gymrow = [gymurl, address_line.text.strip()]
                print('type 2:', gymrow)
                gymwriter.writerow(gymrow)
                time.sleep(3)
                continue # go back to `for`            
            except Exception as ex:
                print('ex:', ex)

            try:
                address_line = sub_soup.find('p', {'class': 'm-b-grid'})
                gymrow = [gymurl, address_line.text.strip()]
                print('type 3:', gymrow)
                gymwriter.writerow(gymrow)
                time.sleep(3)
                continue # go back to `for`            
            except Exception as ex:
                print('ex:', ex)
```

Comment: code without indentations is useless.  BTW: your code works for me for 2nd type of page but I found 3rd type of page https://www.lifetime.life/life-time-locations/fl-coral-gables.html and it needs another `try/except on 2nd type and 3rd type.